# Why does Obito only have 6 reanimated jinchuriki when he fights with Naruto and Bee,

Tags: naruto

I thought Obito got 1-7 and he said in the fight "6 against 2 is unfair" to Naruto im confused af.

episode 325 btw.

Answer (score 5):

He has extracted the Bijuus with one to seven tails but the former Jinchuuriki of the Ichibi - Gaara - is still alive.
Another reason is that he is controlling them using the Six Paths of Pain

> an Outer Path technique that allows a Rinnegan user to manipulate **up to six bodies** as though they are their own.

[Wiki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Six_Paths_of_Pain)

Comment: This is also the reason why later on Gaara has to help whent taking out the Ichibi from Obito, as Naruto didn't encounter him during that fight and didn't get a portion of his chakra.

Comment: wowwwwwww I didnt think of that